# A way to see code change results faster in vscode extension development

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am working on a extension and what to check every small change I need to reload the extension and wait for it to load and then execute the command. I tried looking to automate this process and alternatively to have a live change refresh but was unsuccessful in finding anything relevant.